# Is it good for SEO if I attach a picture on my Tumblr text post using HTML?

Tags: html, images, google-image-search, tumblr

I have a Tumblr blog and I'm using a custom domain for the Tumblr blog. For blogging I need to add images in my text blog.

If I use `<img src...` HTML code to attach a picture, will it refer to my article when someone found a picture that I have posted on my website?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google will show the source of the image when image from your blog is presented to a visitor searching with a relevant term.

It will be shown like this:
[image: Google Image Search]